# how to get all related subcategories and their parents

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have this myqsql db table:

| id | parent_id | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | two. |
| 3 | 0 | three |
| 4 | 0 | four. |
| 6 | 2 | child1. |
| 7 | 2 | child2. |
| 8 | 7 | child3. |
| 10 | 8 | child4. |

what am willing to achieve is an array that contains parents and children not as a tree:
such as:

```
[ 
        {
          "id": "4",
          "parent_id": "0",
          "label": "four",
          "nodes": []
        },
        {
          "id": "3",
          "parent_id": "0",
          "label": "three",
          "nodes": []
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "parent_id": "0",
          "label": "two",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "id": "6",
              "parent_id": "2",
              "label": "child1."
            },
            {
              "id": "7",
              "parent_id": "2",
              "label": "child2."
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "parent_id": "7",
                "label": "child3."
            },
            {
                  "id": "10",
                  "parent_id": "8",
                  "label": "child4."
            },
                 ]
        }
]
```

I did try writing a code but am not getting the same structure.
have a look:

```
 function FoldersChilds($parent_id = 0){
        global $wpdb;
        $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM customer_categories_dropbox_folders WHERE parent_id = $parent_id ORDER BY label ASC");
        if(!empty($query)){
            foreach($query as $row){
                array_push($query,FoldersChilds($row->id)) ;
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
    function FolderscategoryTree($parent_id = 0){
        global $wpdb;
        $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM customer_categories_dropbox_folders WHERE parent_id = $parent_id ORDER BY label ASC");
        if(!empty($query)){
            foreach($query as $row){
                $row->nodes =  FoldersChilds($row->id);
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }
 FolderscategoryTree()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could cycle before on subcategories building an array with index the parent category and data array with all subcategory
something like:

```
$subCategories[$parent_id][] = ["id" => "10","parent_id"=> "8","label"= "child4."];
```

So now when you cycle on main categories you can add under nodes the all array created like:

```
array("id"        => "2",
      "parent_id" => "0",
      "label"     => "two",
      "nodes"     => $subCategories[$IdMainCateogy] //in this case 2
);
```

Comment: this works but i was looking for better solution.Thanks in advanced